# Unable to reproduce an example from JWT spec (RFC 7519) and JWS spec (RFC 7571)

Tags: web, encryption, jwt

I am trying to go deep to understand what JWT really is by heart, so I decide to go to the specs.

The first example there seems to have successfully stop me from going any further.

This example from [JWT spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3.1), for which the [JWS spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#appendix-A.1) provides much more context, is showcasing how a JWT is created.

For the header, it has

```json
{
  "typ":"JWT",
  "alg":"HS256"
}
```

which is base64 encoded into `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLA0KICJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9`;

For the payload, it has

```json
{
  "iss": "joe",
  "exp": 1300819380,
  "http://example.com/is_root": true
}
```

which is based64-encoded into `eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ`

**By the way, I learned from this [post](https://coolaj86.com/articles/sign-jwt-webcrypto-vanilla-js/) that the based64 string used in JWT is not exactly the same as what `btoa` returns**

The problematic part is the signature.

In JWS, it says the example uses a symmetric key to sign the header and payload, which is represented in [jwk](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#ref-JWK) format as

```json
{
  "kty": "oct",
  "k": "AyM1SysPpbyDfgZld3umj1qzKObwVMkoqQ-EstJQLr_T-1qS0gZH75aKtMN3Yj0iPS4hcgUuTwjAzZr1Z9CAow"
}
```

the signed data after base64-encoding is `dBjftJeZ4CVP-mB92K27uhbUJU1p1r_wW1gFWFOEjXk`

I attempted to reproduce this example in the browser. Here is my code

```js
(async () => {

    const header = {
        typ: "jwt",
        alg: "HS256"
    };
    const payload = {
        "iss": "joe",
        "exp": 1300819380,
        "http://example.com/is_root": true
    };

    const headerEncoded = strToSafeUrlBase64(JSON.stringify(header));
    console.log('header', headerEncoded);
    // prints out eyJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
    // Same as Example

    const payloadEncoded = strToSafeUrlBase64(JSON.stringify(payload));
    console.log('payload', payloadEncoded);
    // prints out eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLCJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
    // Same as Example


    const _key = {
        kty: "oct",
        k: "AyM1SysPpbyDfgZld3umj1qzKObwVMkoqQ-EstJQLr_T-1qS0gZH75aKtMN3Yj0iPS4hcgUuTwjAzZr1Z9CAow"
    }
    const HmacKeyParams = {
        name: "HMAC",
        hash: "SHA-256"
    };
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'jwk',
        _key,
        HmacKeyParams,
        true,
        ['sign', 'verify']);

    const signedValue = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC', key, new TextEncoder().encode(`${headerEncoded}.${payloadEncoded}`));

    console.log(uint8ToBase64(new Uint8Array(signedValue)));
    // this prints out _Y6kHA7DqgEFgqbaKMMCGUwPuZMMczSXV0w34CfblCA
    // not the same as the example !!

    function strToSafeUrlBase64(bin) {
        return btoa(bin)
            .replace(/\+/g, '-')
            .replace(/\//g, '_')
            .replace(/=+/g, '');
    }

    function uint8ToBase64(uint8) {
        let s = '';
        uint8.forEach(b => s += String.fromCharCode(b));
        return strToSafeUrlBase64(s);
    }

})();
```

What am I missing there?

**I am a complete amateur in terms of cryptography, so don't hold your words and bash me with the every hard truth**

Comment: Your question is very well written up until the point where you have a problem. I don't see how your final code is supposed to behave and how it actually behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different signature is caused by the following reasons:

- the RFC uses for `typ` `JWT` in the header, while the posted code applies `jwt`.
- the RFC uses a linebreak and a blank (`0x0d0a20`) after a comma in the JSON string, while the posted code lacks the linebreak and blank.

For this reason, the Base64 encoded header and payload differ in the posted JavaScript code and in the RFC:

```
JavaScript: eyJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
RFC:        eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLA0KICJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9

JavaScript: eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLCJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
RFC:        eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
```

and hence the signature.

If these differences are fixed, the signature from the RFC results:

```js
(async () => {

    const header = {
        typ: "JWT",                                                             // Replace jwt by JWT
        alg: "HS256"
    };
    const payload = {
        "iss": "joe",
        "exp": 1300819380,
        "http://example.com/is_root": true
    };

    const headerStringified = JSON.stringify(header).replace(/,/g,',\r\n ');   // Replace comma by comma, linebreak and blank
    const headerEncoded = strToSafeUrlBase64(headerStringified); 
    console.log('header', headerEncoded.replace(/(.{65})/g,'$1\n'));

    const payloadStringified = JSON.stringify(payload).replace(/,/g,',\r\n '); // Replace comma by comma, linebreak and blank
    const payloadEncoded = strToSafeUrlBase64(payloadStringified); 
    console.log('payload', payloadEncoded.replace(/(.{65})/g,'$1\n'));

    const _key = {
        kty: "oct",
        k: "AyM1SysPpbyDfgZld3umj1qzKObwVMkoqQ-EstJQLr_T-1qS0gZH75aKtMN3Yj0iPS4hcgUuTwjAzZr1Z9CAow"
    }
    const HmacKeyParams = {
        name: "HMAC",
        hash: "SHA-256"
    };
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'jwk',
        _key,
        HmacKeyParams,
        true,
        ['sign', 'verify']);

    const signedValue = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC', key, new TextEncoder().encode(`${headerEncoded}.${payloadEncoded}`));

    console.log('signature', uint8ToBase64(new Uint8Array(signedValue)).replace(/(.{65})/g,'$1\n'));

    function strToSafeUrlBase64(bin) {
        return btoa(bin)
            .replace(/\+/g, '-')
            .replace(/\//g, '_')
            .replace(/=+/g, '');
    }

    function uint8ToBase64(uint8) {
        let s = '';
        uint8.forEach(b => s += String.fromCharCode(b));
        return strToSafeUrlBase64(s);
    }

})();
```

Comment: the strange part in the RFC example is, that they encoded the header and payload including linebreaks and spaces, while usually JSON.stringify strips all whitespace, which makes sense to get the shortest possible result. I coulddn't even recreate the signature from the example on jwt.io, because all whitespace is stripped.

Comment: wow! It's my bad for not checking the encoded payload and header byte by byte. But even I'd done that, I still could not figure out what is missing there. Your answer saved my life, literally. Thanks!
I can reproduce the example now.

Comment: @jps - RFC7515 describes the (rather unconventional) encoding (A.1.1): _Note that ambiguities can arise due to differing platform representations of line breaks (CRLF versus LF), differing spacing at the beginning and ends of lines, whether the last line has a terminating line break or not, and other causes. In the representation used in this example the first line has no leading or trailing spaces, a CRLF line break (13, 10) occurs between the first and second lines, the second line has one leading space (32) and no trailing spaces, and the last line does not have a terminating line break._